I can not get an animation in jupyter notebook
When I run the code below in VSC or directly run a script via the command line in linux, I get the sought animation. Since I have done most part of the work in jupyter notebook, which I am running locally (not google colab), I want to get the animation in the jupyter notebook which unfortunately is not providing the animation. I see a plot which is remaining static. Can you help make the animation run in jupyter notebook ? I thank you. Here is the code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

# Define the kinetic operator (Fourier space)
def kinetic_operator(psi, N, mu, epsilon, tau):
    k_vals = np.fft.fftfreq(N, epsilon) * 2 * np.pi  # Discrete k-values for FFT
    K_vals = (2 * (np.sin(np.pi * k_vals / N)**2) / (mu * epsilon**2))  # Eigenvalues of K
    psi_k = fft(psi)  # Transform to Fourier space
    psi_k = psi_k * np.exp(-1j * tau * K_vals)  # Apply kinetic operator in k-space
    return ifft(psi_k)  # Transform back to real space

# Define the potential operator (diagonal in real space)
def potential_operator(psi, V, tau, half=False):
    factor = np.exp(-1j * V * tau / 2) if half else np.exp(-1j * V * tau)
    return factor * psi

# Strang splitting integrator
def strang_splitting_integrator(psi, V, N, tau, mu, epsilon):
    # Apply half-step potential, full-step kinetic, and another half-step potential
    psi_half_potential = potential_operator(psi, V, tau, half=True)
    psi_kinetic = kinetic_operator(psi_half_potential, N, mu, epsilon, tau)
    psi_new = potential_operator(psi_kinetic, V, tau, half=True)
    return psi_new

# Animation function with optimizations
def animate_wavefunction(N, V, psi0, mu, epsilon, tau, steps=200, interval=50):
    x = np.linspace(0, N * epsilon, N)
    psi = np.copy(psi0)  # Starting point for the wavefunction

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line_prob, = ax.plot(x, np.abs(psi)**2, color='g', linestyle='--', label="Probability density")
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)  # Adjust based on the scale of |psi|^2
    ax.set_xlim(0, N * epsilon)
    ax.set_title("Time Evolution of Wavefunction")
    ax.set_xlabel("Position")
    ax.set_ylabel("Probability Density")
   #plt.show()

# The update function for the animation
def update(frame):
    nonlocal psi  # Ensure we update the original psi
    # Update the wavefunction using Strang-Splitting integrator
    psi = strang_splitting_integrator(psi, V, N, tau, mu, epsilon)
    line_prob.set_ydata(np.abs(psi)**2)  # Update probability density
    return line_prob,  # Return the updated line object for blitting

# Create the animation using FuncAnimation
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(steps), interval=interval)#, blit=True)
    plt.show()
    return ani

# Set up parameters for the simulation
N = 200  # Decrease the number of lattice points to improve performance
mu = 1.0  # Mass of particle
epsilon = 0.1  # Small spatial grid spacing for a better approximation of the continuum
tau = 0.1  # Time step for accurate evolution
steps = 200  # Number of time steps for animation

# Initial wavefunction (Gaussian wave packet)
x = np.linspace(0, N * epsilon, N)
psi0 = np.exp(-(x - N * epsilon / 2)**2 / (2.0 * (N * epsilon / 20)**2))

psi0 /= np.sqrt(epsilon) * np.linalg.norm(psi0)  # Normalize wavefunction

# Define potential V (free particle case)
V = np.zeros(N)  # No potential energy (free particle)

# Run the animation
ani = animate_wavefunction(N, V, psi0, mu, epsilon, tau, steps=steps, interval=50)


"... I have done most part of the work in jupyter notebook, which I am running locally (not google colab),...." Okay, but what version of Jupyter Notebook? In addition to that important point, you don't provide many details. Do other examples of animations work and your code is the issue? This isn't a minimal, reproducible example (MRE). When I try to run what you provide I get SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'psi' found. Then if I comment out that I get NameError: name 'fig' is not defined. steps is defined after it is invoked in what you provided. The guide ....

 How do I ask a good question? emphasizes including a minimal, reproducible example under 'Help others reproduce the problem' and covers that you should try to run that in fresh environment and see if it runs as you expect. (See " Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question", in the guide.)

You also don't state anywhere in this post what this animation should do? It looks like you just threw in every piece of code in some arbitrary order for the single codeblock you provide. (I see two occurrences of ani = ?!??! What is that about? Please read the guide and follow it.)  As for starting with code that works for animations, you can go here and try clicking on the badge next to 'Jupyter Notebook 7+:' . The examples there work. The ones using FuncAnimation() are towards the bottom of the notebook that opens.

There is no syntax error shown in my case. I thus could not report about any errors. In jupyter notebook I also do not get any error. I am shown a wave which is static. TO the contrary in VSC I get what I want and that is an animation, a wave animation. There was nothing more to say in the text. The part any=  is not redundant.

Yes, ani = is redundant. You clobber ani you assigned once with another. And why is return ani not indented? Did you restart your kernel and just paste in that code? Did it run as copied and pasted? I provided you a fresh place to run it by launching from there. Did you try running it there?
